# Loading protocol buffer in ruby or java similar to node

Tags: ruby, grpc

I have a `.proto` file that contains my schema and service definition. I'm looking for a method in ruby/java that is similar to how Node loads and parses it (code below). Looking at the grpc ruby gem, I don't see anything that can replicate how Node does it.

Digging around I see this (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6708) which states that dynamically loading `.proto` files is only available in node. Hopefully, someone can provide me with an alternative.

Use case: Loading `.proto` files dynamically as provided in the client but I can only use either ruby or java to do it.

```
let grpc = require("grpc");
let loader = require("@grpc/proto-loader");

let packageDefinition = loader.loadSync(file.file, {});
let parsed = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
```

Comment: There is not such a way in Java, since you do not directly interact with `.proto` files at runtime. You have to pre-compile the `.proto` files to `.java` and use it as Java source.

Comment: There is also no such way in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been giving this a try for the past few month and it seems like Node is the only way to read a protobuf file on runtime. Hopefully this helps anyone in the future that needs it.